# Jquery Bootstrap modal box is not working with check validation in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like to check bootstrap modal form validation before call ajax request , i have used following script for it but validation is not work proper and also after filled form and submit form `submitHandler` is not called or ajax call is not work.

Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        jQuery("#agent_form").validate({
            rules: {
              vname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
              },
              action: "required"
            },
            messages: {
              vname: {
                required: "Please enter some data",
                minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
              },
              action: "Please provide some data"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {                 
                    var ajaxurl = jQuery("#ajaxurl").val();
                    var name =jQuery('#inputName').val();
                    var phone_number =jQuery('#phone_number').val();
                    var useId =jQuery("#data_id").val();                    
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : ajaxurl,
                        type : 'post',
                        data : {
                            action : 'add_new_agent',
                            ag_id : useId,
                            ag_name : name,
                            phone_number:phone_number
                        },
                        success : function( response ) {
                            if(response =='Success'){
                                jQuery('#success_message').fadeIn().html(response);  
                                jQuery("#success_message").addClass("alert alert-success");
                              setTimeout(function(){  
                                jQuery("#success_message").addClass("alert alert-success");
                                jQuery('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow"); 
                                  jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
                              }, 2000); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

HTML Code...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            <div id="error_message" class="ajax_response1" style="float:left"></div>
            <div id="success_message" class="ajax_response1" style="float:left"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form  role="form" id="agent_form">
                    <input id="ajaxurl" name="action" value="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>" type="hidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="data_id" id="data_id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <input name="vname" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="phone_number" class="form-control" id="phone_number" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                    </div>                    
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" id="add_agent" >SUBMIT</button>        
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Validation is not work and also `submitHandler` not call.

Comment: any console messages??

Comment: Are you sure validation js included?

Comment: Yes, i have included validation js but sometimes it's work but when i used submit handler then validation and submit handler is not work

Comment: please use this $(".modal").modal('show');  instead jQuery('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
you need to remove jQuery('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { line code. and add validate in separate. i mean : $("#agent_form").validate({})

Comment: please create a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code,

1. Submit button should be inside the "form", not outside
2. button type should be "submit" not button

I have edited your code, use the following

```js
jQuery(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal', function (e) {
        jQuery("#agent_form").validate({
            rules: {
              vname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
              },
              action: "required"
            },
            messages: {
              vname: {
                required: "Please enter some data",
                minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
              },
              action: "Please provide some data"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {                 
                    var ajaxurl = jQuery("#ajaxurl").val();
                    var name =jQuery('#inputName').val();
                    var phone_number =jQuery('#phone_number').val();
                    var useId =jQuery("#data_id").val();                    
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : ajaxurl,
                        type : 'post',
                        data : {
                            action : 'add_new_agent',
                            ag_id : useId,
                            ag_name : name,
                            phone_number:phone_number
                        },
                        success : function( response ) {
                            if(response =='Success'){
                                jQuery('#success_message').fadeIn().html(response);  
                                jQuery("#success_message").addClass("alert alert-success");
                              setTimeout(function(){  
                                jQuery("#success_message").addClass("alert alert-success");
                                jQuery('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow"); 
                                  jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
                              }, 2000); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!-- The below scripts and styles are for demo purpose, no need to include in your code -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!-- The above scripts and styles are for demo purpose, no need to include in your code -->

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">demo</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            <div id="error_message" class="ajax_response1" style="float:left"></div>
            <div id="success_message" class="ajax_response1" style="float:left"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->
        
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" id="agent_form">
                    <input id="ajaxurl" name="action" value="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>" type="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="data_id" id="data_id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <input name="vname" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="phone_number" class="form-control" id="phone_number" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" id="add_agent" >SUBMIT</button>        
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```